# Passing a custom authorization token to the backend in WSO2 is not giving the expected result

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 APIM-2.6.0 and I would like to pass a custom token. For which I have used a token exchange mechanism in mediation Policies, In flow. As per the instructions provided on WSO2 documentation from the below link,

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/APIGateway/MessageMediation/passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/

Token exchange xml used,

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TokenExchange">
    <property name="Custom" expression="get-property('transport', 'Custom')"/>
    <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('Custom')" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="Custom" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
</sequence>
```

On the management console of API Store when I provide the existing bearer token in the header parameter and when I execute, the response is,

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
Code: 200
```

But, when I copy the same curl command from API Store UI and run through command prompt, it gives the response and it works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you add the custom header in your curl command? Could you please share the curl command that is not working?

Comment: Hi Menaka, Thanks for the response. The curl command which wso2 is generating on API Store UI is not working on API Store UI but, the same command if i copy and execute through command prompt its working fine and getting the response.Anyways the below is the command

Comment: curl -k -X POST "https://localhost:8245/testAPI/1.0.0/import?tId=<tenantId>&Content-Type=application%2Fjson&Accept=application%2Fjson" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Custom: Bearer <accessToken>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 60500405-ca02-3c34-bffb-1d81f4ac7433" -d "{<payLoad>}"

Comment: The generated curl may not have the Custom auth header. Therefore, it will not work.  You have to manually add the custom auth header to the curl generated from the store swagger ui.

Comment: Hi Menaka, Thanks again. The generated curl is having the Custom auth header. I am adding it. If its not present when I copy paste the same url to the command prompt it should not work but, its working fine through command prompt without making any changes to it.